# Apostrophe in Querystring in Firefox

Tags: html, http, asp-classic

In my project I am passing `name` as a querystring. When there is an aphostrophe `'` in the name it's not working in Firefox. It's working fine in IE. In Firefox it's replacing the apostrophe with `&#39;` How do I fix this problem? I know this can be fixed very easily in .net. Unfortunately my project is in ASP Classic. Any suggestions?

Comment: Passing from where to where? Server to browser? Browser to server? Via plain HTML? JavaScript? How are you determining it is being changed to `&#39;` (which is how you express `'` in HTML)? How do you define "working"?

Comment: `&#39;` is one of the ways to escape the [apostrophe](http://www.hybridelephant.com/computer/tutorial/spechar.html). Firefox is doing the **correct** thing and escaping this character, IE is not. In your ASP page simply use Server.UrlDecode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if I got your question correctly, did you try using Server.URLEncode?

Comment: How I am going to Decode it. In Fire fox the Querystring value is encoded as &#39;. How I am going to decode it.